# How can i bind a IsSelected Property to a textblock

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textblock

my treeview is populated with textblock items.
If a user clicks on a textblock, i want to set a property in my model called "isSelected".
But : the textblock have no Property IsSelected.
How can i Implement this ?
Derive from textblock and add a Property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [TreeViewItem.IsSelected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.isselected.aspx) property. You will have to specify the custom style for all items of the tree view.

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Hi, for me it doesnt work : I have a RootNode with an ObserveblaeCollection of SubNodes , this SubNode implements the Property IsSelected.

Comment: Hi Andrew it works ! Sry my XAML Editor told me, it caonnot access the Property ;-)